# Is it possible to dial two or more numbers in same time - classic SIM based calls - Dual SIM devices

Tags: android, dual-sim, conference, dialing

- Is it possible to dial two numbers in same time ?

  Maybe  android.telecom.Conference
  can help me , but there is no lot of examples for this class usage.

android.telecom.Conference
Doc say :

> Represents a conference call which can contain any number of
>   Connection objects.

Than can be sim based connections . 
I have no need for video call , i need just ringing /answer or reject .

Maybe dual sim devices ?

More :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcVBZkA2kI8

[(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Conference.html](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/Conference.html))

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible you can use views as visible/invisible/gone when you are entering it